# Are Relay and Graphql RESTful?

Tags: rest, graphql, relay

Although there are many differences between Graphql APIs and common REST APIs implemented with HTTP, I am wondering if these differences are syntactical or if Relay and Graphql are fundamentally non-RESTful. If so which constraint of REST do they violate?

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL is not RESTful as it doesn't use uris and http methods to express the nature of the operations.
You have one route (for example: /graphql) that you send all operations to - both queries and mutations, on all types of entities.

Comment: I believe an application can be RESTful without specifically implementing URIs and HTTP methods. That just happens to be the implementation for the World Wide Web. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Daniel an application cannot be RESTful without URIs, HTTP and the Web because REST isn't some general software architecture (like, idk, micro services or whatever) but a convention of how to use said URIs and HTTP protocol for a CRUD application.

As its name - "representational state transfer" - suggests, it deals with how to represent state over HTTP (of course you can implement the same conventions over other communication protocols by emulating HTTP's attributes - URI, method, etc - over that protocol)

Comment: I suspect that this answer is very poor and misleading. I understand that REST "REpresentational State Transfer" is an ideal where a server transfers a representation of it's state/operations for transforming state to a client. I don't think the means of representation is specified...

Comment: A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723123/is-a-graphql-api-restful-by-default