# Is a GraphQL API RESTful by default?

Tags: rest, graphql

My understanding of REST is simply that a resource needs some means of self-describing itself. My understanding is that this isn't specifically tied to any one protocol (i.e. HTTP) and that there are theoretically numerous ways of achieving this. This is based on an answer to a SO question here: [SOAP vs REST (differences)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884295/soap-vs-rest-differences) (and unlike the terrible answer to this question: [Are Relay and Graphql RESTful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709614/are-relay-and-graphql-restful))

Since a GraphQL API is self-describing via [introspection](https://graphql.org/learn/introspection/), doesn't that mean that GraphQL is RESTful by default since a client can use introspection to figure out how to query it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While GraphQL is [often mentioned as the replacement](https://medium.com/chute-engineering/graphql-in-the-age-of-rest-apis-b10f2bf09bba) for REST, both tackle different problems actually.

REST, to start with, is not a protocol but just a style, which, if applied correctly and fully, just decouples clients from servers. A server following the REST principals will therefore provide the client with any information needed to take further steps. A client initially starts without any a-priori knowledge and learns on the fly through issuing requests and processing responses. HATEOAS describes the interaction model a REST architectue should be build upon. It thereby states that a link should be used to request new information which drives its internal flow. On utilizing similar representation to Web forms (HTML) a server can teach a client on needed inputs. Through the [affordance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIv9YR1bMwY&t=817) of the respective elements a client knows, without any need for external documentation, what to do. I.e. It might find a couple of options to chose one or multiple options from, enter or update some freetext or push some buttons. In HTML forms usually trigger a POST request and send the entered data as `application/x-www-form-urlenceded` to the server though the form element itself may define something different.

While REST is protocol agnostic, meaning it can be build up ontop of many protocols, HTTP is probably the most prominent one. A common sample for a RESTful client is the Web browser we are all to familiar with. It will start by invoking either a bookmarked URI or invoke one entered in the address bar and progress from there on.

HTTP doesn't specify the representation the request or response has to be sent in but leaves that to clients and servers negotiating them. This helps in decoupling as both client and servers can rely on the common interface (HTTP) and only bind strongly onto the known media types used to exchange data in. A peer not being able to process a document in a certain representation (due to the lack of the respective mime type support) will indicate his other peer via a respective HTTP status code that it does not understand, and therefore can't serve, the requested media-type format. The media type, which is just a human readable documentation of the syntax and the semantics of the data payload, is therefore the most important part in a REST architecture. Even [Fielding claimed](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven):

> A REST API should spend almost all of its descriptive effort in defining the media type(s) used for representing resources and driving application state, or in defining extended relation names and/or hypertext-enabled mark-up for existing standard media types. Any effort spent describing what methods to use on what URIs of interest should be entirely defined within the scope of the processing rules for a media type (and, in most cases, already defined by existing media types). [Failure here implies that out-of-band information is driving interaction instead of hypertext.]

A media type teaches a peer how to parse and interpret the received payload and to actually make sense out of it, though plenty of people still confuse REST for a JSON based HTTP API with over-engineered URIs they put to much effort in to give the URI some kind of logical sense when actually neither client nor server will interpret it anyway as they will probably use the link relation name given for the URI.

GraphQL on the other hand is a basically just a query language which gives the client the power to request specific fields and elements it wants to retrieve from the server. It is, loosely speaking, some kind of SQL for the Web, or as [Fielding termed it](https://twitter.com/fielding/status/1051973613799129089) just a `Remote Data Access (RDA)`. It therefore has to have some knowledge of the available data beforehand which couples clients somehow to the server. If the server will rename some of the fields, the client might not be able to retrieve that kind of information further, though I'm not a GraphQL expert.

As stated above, REST is often confused for a JSON based HTTP API that allows to perform queries on directly mapped DB entries/entities. Keep in mind that REST doesn't prohibit this, though its focus is on the decoupling of peers not the retrieval aspect of some Web exposed database entries. As Jim Webber pointed out in a great talk back in 2011 in REST you don't simply expose database tables, you create a domain application protocol which clients will follow along [like in a text-based computer game or in a typical Webshop system on the internet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=420).

Especially the linked introspection documentation of GraphQL reminds me of reflection in Java, which couples to the actual class model available. If something along the datamodel changes, how does the GraphQL interaction behave? Is it able to change and adapt? Is a client built for one API able to work with an other API out of the box? All these are basically requirements for a true RESTful client. It basically has to adept to changes in future as the server is free to evolve anytime. It further shouldn't assume certain endpoints returning [certain types](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) but use content type negotiation to request a representation it can work upon.

These should give you enough insights to determine for yourself whether GraphQL can be RESTful or not. In my opinion it isn't, but my insights into GraphQL are rather limited, TBH.

---

> Because graphql publishes Metadata about its types, it's entirely plausible (I think) to build a graphql client that could consume any graphql endpoint ...

SOAP did the exact same thing, though it was still an RPC protocol. A client could look up the `...?wsdl` information at run-time and then generate a request according to the schema defined in the WSDL dynamically, though what usually happened was that some pre-generated stub-classes were generated based on the WSDL data that got compiled into a specific client. A client dynamically generating a request still needed a routine that defines what message-type to create and what data the message required as input.

While SOAP could potentially define multiple endpoints within a WSDL, in most cases only one was defined though. This endpoint usually only operates on POST requests even when later on (SOAP 1.2) GET would have been possible also.

According to [Fielding's thesis](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)

> REST uses a resource identifier to identify the particular resource involved in an interaction between components.

, what would be the resource identifier in GraphQL? [GraphQL's documentation](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/) states that

> ... In contrast, GraphQL's conceptual model is an entity graph. As a result, entities in GraphQL are not identified by URLs. Instead, a GraphQL server operates on a single URL/endpoint, usually /graphql, and all GraphQL requests for a given service should be directed at this endpoint.

Similar to SOAP, all the request are targeted towards a single endpoint. This has some impact if you consider caching, which is a further constraint REST implies. How are responses cacheable if the URI is the key used to store the response in the cache?

While all of the aggregation stuff and the flexibility may be nice from a consumer perspective, they are, probably, not in line with the constraints of REST, though Fielding himself claimed that REST is not applicable in all situations and that [designers should select a style that fits their needs as not every style is the "silver bullet" to each problem](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/software_arch.htm#sec_1_5). Even [Mike Amundsen](https://twitter.com/mamund/status/1051638736235184129) stated that GraphQL violates at least 3 constraints imposed by the REST architecture, even though GraphQL seems to have changed the default retrieval method from POST to GET since.

Usually, if you aim for long-living APIs that should be free to evolve in future and that has to deal with lots of clients, especially ones not under your direct control, this is when REST starts to shine. Fielding admits that most [developers have problems when thinking long-term](https://www.infoq.com/articles/roy-fielding-on-versioning/). For a single frontend-to-backend system or for a tailor-made client interacting with the own API, REST is not the architecture one should probably follow.

Last but not least, in a later tweet [Fielding stated](https://twitter.com/fielding/status/1052976631374000128?lang=en)

> There is no such thing as a REST endpoint. There are resources. A countably infinite set of resources bound only by restrictions on URL length. A client can POST to a REST service to create a resource that is a GraphQL query, and then GET that resource with all benefits of REST…

which I interpret as, don't focus to much on justifying whether GraphQL is REST or not, but think about how you can integrate its benefits into the overall design.

Comment: Because graphql publishes Metadata about its types, it's entirely plausible (I think) to build a graphql client that could consume any graphql endpoint, which to me is similar in concept to an HTTP endpoint where a client can use hypertext to determine what resources are available.

Comment: In both cases I think that's nice from a user perspective - no documentation is required to consume a graphql if you have a nice client that you can test with (I.E. GraphiQl vs swagger).