# GraphQL for Reads and Rest for Writes

Tags: rest, graphql, server-to-server

In the context of **server to server communication** and more precisely **within different microservices**, is it a good idea to use GraphQL?

The idea is to **allow the consumers to only fetch relevant fields for them**. One can build the field projections for REST GET endpoints themselves or can use a library to do so e.g. [Rest.li](https://linkedin.github.io/rest.li/Projections).

In the era where GraphQL exists to solve similar problems, would it make more sense to use GraphQL for READs (This is where GraphQL brings a lot of value) and still use REST for write operations (There are some compelling reasons for which moving to GraphQL for writes is not possible at the moment)?

Comment: How does the client know which data is relevant to it? Without a-priori knowledge of the available properties of a certain resource I doubt that this is really a good design. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723123/is-a-graphql-api-restful-by-default/58558884#58558884) I summarized Fieldings take on how GraphQL could be combined with REST, where Fielding suggest: `A client can POST to a REST service to create a resource that is a GraphQL query, and then GET that resource with all benefits of REST…`

Comment: There is an existing REST resource say with 10-20 fields as part of the GET response. Most of the services would need 1-3 fields (mostly different based on the client). In a way the client knows what fields it needs. Would putting a GraphQL api for READs in this case would make sense? Essentially we'll end up with REST and GraphQL in our stack. Is having both for server to server communication a bad idea?

Comment: Technically it might, though whether this solution is "RESTful" is a different story. I.e. you might not be able to cache GraphQL responses easily as all queries target the same endpoint and therefore use the same URI (= cache key). As such this would violate the cacheable constraint REST has. You could, however, use either dedicated media types that specify which properties to return or make use of [resources that support views or the like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35495385/rest-services-and-multiple-representations-of-same-object-with-different-fields/35532212#35532212)

Comment: Thanks @RomanVottner for your time and response. Wanted  to compare what is possible today with GraphQL compared to what we have been doing only with REST.